# "FB is not defined" AND "init not called with valid version" in equal measure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you go from my [blog](https://www.passcash.me/blog) to a new browser for a blog [post](https://www.passcash.me/post/Test%20Post%202) or if you just open the link directly like the one below, it shows the following errors in equal measure, seemingly randomly:
1) FB is not defined
2) init not called with valid version

I've looked through a number of links for a solution to this problem including:
[FB init function gives wrong version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019877/fb-init-function-gives-wrong-version-error)
[FB not defined and prompts error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157924/fb-not-defined-and-prompts-error)
[FB is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019207/fb-is-not-defined)
[Facebook comments load inconsistently with Angular Fullstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187606/facebook-comments-load-inconsistently-with-angular-fullstack/36204994#36204994)

A test post from my site: https://www.passcash.me/post/Test%20Post%202

This an Angular Fullstack project with the following code:

**index.html:**

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>         
        (function(d, s, id){
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.5&appId=981622408578699&cookie=true&xfbml=true";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

I tried a number of different versions of js.src as mentioned on the 
[FB init function gives wrong version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019877/fb-init-function-gives-wrong-version-error) 
link

**post.html**

```
<script>
  FB.XFBML.parse();
</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href={{webAddress}} data-layout="button_count"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href={{webAddress}} data-width="100%" data-numposts="10"></div>
```

**post.controller.js**

```
if (typeof FB != 'undefined' && FB != null && typeof(FB) != undefined) {
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           FB.XFBML.parse();
         });
 } else {
         console.log("FB is not defined", FB);
         window.location.reload();
      }
```

Please feel free to be heavy handed with your guidance.  If you provide a light touch I probably will not understand.  And yes it is dubious to me that I have FB.XFBML in two places but that has been the only way I can get comments to show up without refreshing the screen, which works when you go to a post from inside the blog but not by opening the post in a new tab or window.

Comment: Why are you using what looks like a typical cache-busting technique when loading the SDK? Maybe that’s the root of your issue – because you are _forcing_ the script to be loaded from the server again, it might not initialize as quickly as it could, if it was simply served from cache on subsequent page loads. Usually there are no problems with the SDK and caching, so you should let the browser handle that as instructed by the server, that is the least likely to cause problems.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the response!  I'm not sure what you mean by cache-busting technique.  What am I doing wrong or how would I address this.  Your suggestion sounds good but I don't know where to begin to test it.

Comment: I mean this: `?d=" + new Date().toISOString()` – you are appending that to the SDK’s address, and since `Date` will be different each time your page loads, it forces the browser to load the script again from the FB servers – because appending this changing value makes them _different_ URLs. The browser could not fetch it from cache even if it wanted – it has never loaded _that_ URL before. (This is wanted in some situations, f.e. if an image has been manipulated server-side, and you want to make sure the client refreshes it – “cache busting.”) So remove that, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @CBroe - thanks. I'd never have guessed. That was one of many suggestions from one of the links.  I didn't understand it but it seemed to work for a lot of people without breaking anything in my local host. Makes sense what you're saying so I'll try it!

Comment: @CBroe I changed it up as you can see in the edit.  It's improved in that at least it comes up after reload but it still does not come up the first time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @CBroe  It also seems to have gotten rid of the FB is not defined error but the other error still remains.

Comment: Well maybe one of your calls to FB.XFBML.parse still comes to early. You can only call additional FB methods, after `fbAsyncInit` event has fired and `FB.init` has been called. When/how does your `post.html` file get loaded into the main page(?), and have you done anything to ensure this happens after the SDK is done initializing?

Comment: @CBroe post.html is a partial; I'm not sure what you mean (or how to determine) when/how it gets loaded to the main page.  What else could/should I do to make sure it fires after the SDK is done initializing?  I'm kind of a newb that has only learned things specific to this project and contributing to it.

Comment: Sorry, I myself am not familiar with Angular … You’ll have to find someone to help you with specifics on that I’m afraid.

Comment: @CBroe - thanks for the suggestions, they've opened up a new question for me to explore.

Comment: Wait, I just now saw your edit: `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.5&appId=981622408578699&cookie=true&xfbml=true` – using that address with the “parameters” in the hash part will make the SDK initialize itself automatically – in that case, you don’t need `fbAsyncInit` (not sure if that will even still fire in that situation) and `FB.init` call any more.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. I did make that change and the current question now reflects the correct update.

Comment: Try and really just embed and initialize the SDK as suggested here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5#loading Plus, they have a section about AngularJS and using the SDK, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs – and that links to this blog post, http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/facebook-authentication-in-your-angularjs-web-app/ – see if either of those contain any useful information maybe on how to get Angular and the SDK to play together nicely.

Comment: @CBroe - I dropped it in just like it shows in the quick start guide in my index.html but without the multiple FB.XFBML in my post.html AND post.controller.js the comments plugin will not load without a refresh.